# Why does JasperReports ignore $!P SQL- ingection?

Tags: sql, parameters, jasper-reports

I am trying to make a report with hard filters where any of the parameters can be presented like -

- "is (not) null"
- "(not) like"
- "!="
- "="
- starts with (like "%_")
  and even have no filter.

So I am trying to insert a whole WHERE clause into the report (except of the first line).
Due to some reason *Jasper* ignores the filer, but I don't understand why.

It alarms me if I try to put more than one *and* in the beginning or if there exists any unnamed alias, so I suppose it is reading somehow.

Putting the parameter in brackets does not help.
Example:

> It does not filter it by the first condition -

```
'''
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE t.status_id=1
and $!P{hello};

$!P{hello} is inserted as "t.land like'%12' and status='REC2' and objid in (1,2,7,9,12)"
'''
```

> I expect it to execute it as:

```
'''
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE t.status_id=1
and t.land like'%12' and status='REC2' and objid in (1,2,7,9,12)
'''
```

But Jasper ignores all the rest. Why is it ignoring the parameter?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show a minimal jrxml and output the ${hello} variabile also in report, I bet it's not what you expect it to be.

Comment: "Show a minimal jrxml and output the ${hello} variabile also in report, I bet it's not what you expect it to be."  - It shows the same text. "You should small and full example to reproduce issue" - Didn't get what you mean.

Comment: Note that the correct syntax is $P!{hello} and not $!P{hello}.  You can enable debug logging for net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter to see the exact query string executed for the report.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I tested my query on the production base, and it worked well, but the data in the test base was incorrect so it looked like it didn't work.
Test your query on the same base)